# @Qualifier("unique_name") in spring to identify a bean uniquely in application context not working?

Tags: spring, annotations, singleton

I have the following scenario:

```
class A  with "bean-a" in wireup.xml  

class B extends A  with "bean-b" in wireup.xml
```

Since `B is also A`, which means there are more than one instance of class **A** in application context.

I want to uniquely identify the singleton instance of class **B**, so I used

```
@Qualifier("unique_name") in class B
```

and

```
<qualifier value="unique_name"/>  in "bean-b" of wireup.xml
```

But the issue is still there, I get message as :

```
No unique bean of type [A] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [A, B]
```

How do I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: isn't bean-a the one that will be ambiguous? There is only one bean of type B, but two of type A in the container. However in your example you're putting the qualifier on B. It seems that you'll need to put it on both A and B or just A but I'm not sure which without trying it.

Comment: you get this at the injection point. What is the definition there?

Comment: @Bozho what do you mean by injection point? I am new so did not understood this

Comment: The field wcich you inject into

Comment: it is @Autowired private B b;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Qualifier should not be put in classB. Instead it should be put along with autowired.
Your class should look like,

```
Class MyClass {

  @AutoWired
  @Qualifier("unique_name")
  private B b;

  //...

}
```

By this means you are telling autowire the b with of type B (type B or A because B is subclass of A) but with a bean definition which has the qualifier "unique_name". The wireup.xml has the qualifier tag assigned to bean-b. Your wireup.xml might look like this

```
<bean id="bean-A" class="com.domain.A" />
<bean id="bean-B" class="com.domain.B"
  <qualifier="unique_name" />
</bean>
```